# Xbindkeys and the equals key

Tags: xbindkeys

How does one bind a key to the "=" key using xbindkeys?

I have tried "=", "equal", and "equals" but none of these seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the string `equal` without quotes. For example, to launch `xclock` with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>=</kbd>:

```
"xclock"
  Alt+equal
```

To find out what to use, use:

```
xbindkeys --key
```